# Differences between no child vs no children

Tags: word-choice

a) They have no child.
b) They have no children.

Are both a) and b) correct? Though b) seems more common.

Comment: The (b) form is more common, to the extent that the (a) form just *sounds* wrong to me. Though "*No child left behind*", by contrast, seems perfectly fine.

Comment: It's the same as *He has no **friend/friends*** - but not the same as *He has no **brain/brains***.

Comment: The (a) form would only be (sensibly) chosen in unusual circumstances, with enabling prior context. It's a formal, and often rather dated usage: 'Both of them are by this time old. and they have no child from their marriage.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p352) has a good entry on this question:

> After *no*, countable nouns are usually plural unless the sense makes a
> singular noun necessary. Compare:
>
> - *He's got no children.* (More natural than *He's got no child.*)
> - *He's got no wife.* (More normal than *He's got no wives.*)

So, *They have no children* is indeed more common and natural than *They have no child*. Conversely, *They have no car* seems more natural than *They have no cars*.

Answer (score 0):

'They have no children' or 'She has no children' is much more common. However 'They have no child' although okay to say seems a bit dramatic when you can say the other version.